# Multidimensional Arrays fro Random Walk Program

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am working on my multidimensional array homework for my C++ class and honestly I am 100% lost on how this is supposed to work. It's the random grid walk and I've found plenty of examples but I am still just not understanding it. I understand what the program is supposed to output but it is the how that has me stumped, logically I just don't get it. If anyone can explain to me what the code is doing and how I'd really appreciate it. I can code it from their it's just trying to understand it that is kicking my butt.

> Requirements and constants for the assignment:

- Libraries: iostream, cstdlib (for stand & rand), ctime (for time)
- const int SIZE = 10; (10 can never show up in the program must call through variable)
- typedef char Grid[SIZE][SIZE];
- Function Prototypes that must be used as shown no less but can add functions.

The mock up we were give of the main program looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

/*** Function Prototypes ***/
bool can_move_up(int i, int j, Grid walk);
bool can_move_up(int i, int j, Grid walk);
bool can_move_up(int i, int j, Grid walk);
bool can_move_up(int i, int j, Grid walk);
void init_array(Grid walk);
void generate_random_walk(Grid walk);
void print_array(Grid walk);
/***************************/



int main(void)
{
const int SIZE = 10;
typedef char Grid[SIZE][SIZE];

Grid walk; // the grid in which the random walk occurs

srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

init_array(walk);
generate_random_walk(walk);
print_array(walk);

return 0;

}
```

This is the code that I have come up with so far. I have not been able to get it to run but I think I'm on the right track I'm just confused on where to go to from here logically. I am stressing that I want to UNDERSTAND LOGICALLY how this works and not have someone do it for me. I'm not a CS or CE major but I do find this stuff interesting.

(I am using classes and have this separated into .cpp & .hpp files but placed the class portion at the beginning of the code for you all to see how my classes are set up and the functions within them are set to work.)

Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


// References these two variables to the other classes through public domain with in class
class BaseClass
{
public:
    const static int SIZE = 10;
    typedef char Grid[SIZE][SIZE]; 
private:

};

// Contains the initialization, generation, and printing functions for the program
class RandomWalkClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    // Initializes the Grid filling all 100 spaces with '.' and starting poin "0,0" with 'A'
    void init_array(Grid walk)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                Grid[i][j] = '.'; // Xcode gives me error for '=' "Expected unqualified-id"
                Grid[0][0] = 'A'; // Xcode gives me error for '=' "Expected unqualified-id"
            }
        }
    }
    // I am honestly not sure what to do with this funciton or what should be included in it's body
    void generate_random_walk(Grid walk)
    {

    }
    // Will print the random walk to the grid
    void print_array(Grid walk)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                cout << Grid[i][j]; // Xcode error "Unexpected type name 'Grid'"
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
   }
private:

};

// Contains the move functions for the program
class MoveDirectionClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    bool can_move_up(int i, int j, Grid walk)
    {
        if (i > 0 && walk[i - 1][j] == '.')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool can_move_down(int i, int j, Grid walk)
    {
        if (i < 9 && walk[i + 1][j] == '.')
        {
           return true;
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    bool can_move_left(int i, int j, Grid walk)
    {
        if (j > 0 && walk[i][j - 1] == '.')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool can_move_right(int i, int j, Grid walk)
    {
        if (j < 9 && walk[i][j + 1] == '.')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
private:

};

#include "program6.hpp"

int main()
{
int i;
int j;
int walk;
int letter;
int move;

// Unsure of where this should go and what it's purpose to the program is (we've never discussed srand in class)
srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

// Calls initialization of program
RandomWalkClass initialize;
initialize.init_array(<#char (*walk)[10]#>);

// randomly chooses 0,1,2,3
move = rand() % 4;

// Runs through alphabet with each move of the switch program
for (letter = 1; letter < 26; letter++)
{
    switch (move)
    {
        case 0:
            MoveDirectionClass up;
            up.can_move_up(<#int i#>, <#int j#>, <#char (*walk)[10]#>);
            break;
        case 1:
            MoveDirectionClass down;
            down.can_move_down(<#int i#>, <#int j#>, <#char (*walk)[10]#>);
            break;
        case 2:
            MoveDirectionClass left;
            left.can_move_left(<#int i#>, <#int j#>, <#char (*walk)[10]#>);
            break;
        case 3:
            MoveDirectionClass right;
            right.can_move_right(<#int i#>, <#int j#>, <#char (*walk)[10]#>);
            break;
        default: break;
    }

}

// Calls the printing of the grid with the random walk
RandomWalkClass generate;
generate.print_array(<#char (*walk)[10]#>);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Grid[i][j] = '.';` is wrong - you defined `Grid` as a type, not a variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, you should start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. *Never add to code that doesn't work.* Have you tried coding a one-dimensional random walk? If you really want help with a specific problem, then make your question about that problem; a little background material or context is all right, but don't post everything you have and ask a dozen specific questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it came to the Unexpected type name you did `typedef Grid` and didn't put it in your class.
Well, just to move from room to room, if you want objects in this room I would do something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Room{
//insert variables here like
int object;
}
typedef struct Room room[5][5];
int main()
{
string direction;
int x;
int y;
room space; //This is the variable to access both the array and the struct
space[0][0].object = 0; //This variable represents what room you start off in and the 0 could represent the type of object or the fact that there is no object.
//Now create rooms [0][0] through [4][4] which is a 5 by 5 area. After that create this.
cout << "Enter W to go north, S for South, D for East, and A for West." << endl;
cin >> direction;
if (direction == "W")
y++;
if (direction == "S")
y--;
if (direction == "D")
x++;
if (direction == "A")
x--;
//Then repeat this code and access the different rooms using space[x][y].object or whatever the variable you want to access from the struct
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns. I also have a game with an example of moving between rooms. My email is joshoheaps@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Grid[i][j] = '.'` and `Grid[i][j] = 'A'`, use

```
walk[i][j] = '.';
walk[0][0] = 'A';
```

Comment: Oh man I feel really stupid on that one! I knew it was a simple error I've just been staring at this and over thinking it way too much already. Thanks man!